# Ratio of unique co-ordinates visited to total co-ordinate visited in a random walk.

Tags: brownian-motion, random-walk

For a random walk in integer valued order pair coordinate, if a particle/agent moves randomly right/left/up/down one unit with equal probability, what is the ratio of unique coordinate visited to total coordinate visited? Is there any analytic way to find this? I use simulations to verify that it is non-zero. Does it converge to any value and what is its relation with dimension?

For example $A$ starts from $(0,0) \rightarrow (0,1) \rightarrow (1,1)\rightarrow (1,0)\rightarrow (1,1)\rightarrow (0,1)\rightarrow (-1,1)\rightarrow (-1,0)$ etc. In this case, $A$ visits $8$ locations but it repeats $2$ locations. So the ratio is $0.75$. If we continue this process, what is the limiting ratio?

In $\textit{Brownian}$ Motion $A$ visits zero infinitely often at the beginning, but how that would help to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by [Dvoretzky & Erdős](https://projecteuclid.org/proceedings/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Second-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/Chapter/Some-Problems-on-Random-Walk-in-Space/bsmsp/1200500239). Specifically, the expected proportion of different sites visited in the first $n$ steps is given (asymptotically) by
$$
\frac{\pi}{\ln n}+O\!\left(\frac{\ln\ln n}{\ln^2 n}\right).
$$